# CSS: does nth-child(n+1) not apply to "display"?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Trying to get an inline list without inserting extra tags between `ul` and `li`. I need to do it this way because essentially the app our clients use to create documents has a "one tag for one value selected" thing going on, otherwise it'd be pretty elementary to just sneak a `<br/>` in there and call it a day.

Please visit http://jsfiddle.net/EkQKL/3/ for a working example of what I'm mucking about with.

I'm using the following CSS:

```
ul {
    margin:0 0 0 2em;
    padding:0 0 0 2em;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-indent:-2em;
    list-style-type:none;
}    

ul li {
    font-weight:normal;
    margin-right:1em;
}

ul li:nth-child(n+1){ /*aye, this is the problem*/
    display:inline;
}
```

...but invariably, this seems to just ignore the n+1 part and apply it to every `li`, which in turn makes the first `li` snuggle the text in the `ul`. Argh.

So if I set it to n+2, I get the result I would expect; the first `li` is 'normal', and the rest all line up horizontally. But setting it to `n+1` I would *expect* it to leave the first element alone, and then apply `display:inline` to all subsequent `li`, but it isn't doing that.

I don't have the ability to really use a lot of classes or add extra HTML elements, so I'm kind of at a loss with this one. The only workaround I have is to place the header outside the `ul` element -- which has other issues with other stylesheets can could be applied to this document.

Is there something about the `nth-child` thing that I'm just overlooking? Or is this more to do with the `display` and how it is being applied?  It 'feels like' a bug, but I'm not trying to presume too much; I may just not be as smart as I think I am. :)

Comment: The number after the `n` tells the counter where to start.

Comment: If you do invalid HTML (like putting content in a `ul` that isn't in a `li`) you shouldn't be surprised at odd behaviour.

Comment: I wasn't aware that it was bad practice to place content which might be considered the title of a list within the `ul` or `ol` tags. If that's true then that's fine -- but it feels a bit counterintuitive

Comment: Since you called me out for bad practice, I feel like you should post it as an answer and let me upvote it

Answer (score 2):

This is simply because `ul li:nth-child(n+1)` indicates that it should style every `li`, that is a child of `ul` - starting at the first child. Essentially there is no difference between this and `ul li {}`, because it will style every child regardless. Therefore `:nth-child(n+1)` wasn't even doing anything.

The reason `:nth-child(n+2)` works, is because it starts by styling the second `li`.

Comment: Perhaps I miscommunicated; it's my goal to have this render "as-if" there were a <br/> between the ul and the first li. Neither n+1 nor n+2 is doing this. I suspect it is a problem with my understanding of `display:inline` at this point.

Comment: @Stick Since they are block level elements to begin with, that is essentially what it does do: http://jsfiddle.net/zPh7Q/ I see a break between the first child and the `ul`

Comment: Yes it is. Apparently, according to other posters it is 'bad practice' to have your lists look like `<ul>Title of List<li>list items</li></ul>`. I did not know this, and it does sort of conflate the issue unfortunately.

Comment: @Stick It's a bad practice to have content within an `ul` that isn't an `li`, http://jsfiddle.net/E2hwz/ The markup in that example is correct, it validates.

Comment: God that's weird. :) All right, it's another case of the poor practice bug, come to get me. I shall henceforth abstain from writing code until it is 110% valid

Comment: @Stick The title obviously isn't part of the list though, so you could easily just place it outside of the `ul`.. http://jsfiddle.net/WdS47/ That's what I would do..

Comment: Yeah unfortunately there are other considerations besides my own work, but that's what I'll be doing from here on out, thanks